# Apache Camel slow startup of routes

Tags: apache-camel

I am using Apache camel to implement dispatcher EIP. There are thousands of messages in a queue which needs to be delivered at different URLs. Each message has its own delivery URL and delivery protocol (ftp,email,http etc).

The way it is been implemented:

- Boot a single camel context, the context is disabled for JMX and the
  loadStatisticsEnabled is set to false on the ManagementStrategy. As
  mentioned in a jira issue, addressed in 2.11.0 version, for disabling
  the background management thread creation.
- For each message a route is being constructed , the message is being
  pushed to the route for delivery.
- After the message is processed route is shutdown and removed from
  context.

Did a small perf test by having 200 threads of dispatcher component, each sharing the same context. 
Observed that the time to start a route increases upto a maximum of 60 seconds while the time to process is in milliseconds.

Issue CAMEL-5675 mentions that this has been fixed but still observing significant time being taken in starting up routes. 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-5675

The route that is being creating for http is

```
from("direct:"+dispatchItem.getID())
.toF("%s?httpClient.soTimeout=%s&disableStreamCache=true", dispatchItem.getEndPointURL(),timeOutInMillis);
```

Each dispatchItem has a unique ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is being active discussed elsewhere, where the user posted this question first: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Slow-startup-of-routes-tp5732356.html